# Execute code from string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm using a metadata approach to process some code. Let's say the following is a string:

```
if $bmi >= 18.5 && $bmi <= 24.9 then return 'healthy' elsif $bmi >= 25 && $bmi <= 29.9 then return 'overweight' elsif $bmi > 30 then return 'obese' end
```

$bmi gets replaced properly, but I then want the code to execute.

Comment: Why do you feel that your metadata approach requires raw strings?  What is the benefit of doing it this way?  There's some context here that's missing that would get you a better answer (the obvious solution is to do regex replace on your symbols then throw it through `eval`, but I would ***strongly*** caution against that right now).

Comment: Find an article that explains Ruby's different eval methods and choose the one that fits your use case. Here's one: http://www.infoq.com/articles/eval-options-in-ruby  (Of course, make sure you really want to do this at all first...)

Comment: Thank you. Eval is actually what I was looking for. That fits, thank you :)

Comment: WAIT, NO!  Don't just blindly use eval!

Comment: The metadata is coming from my side, and is on the server. It is used to evaluate values that come in from the DB and compare them using the code snippet I provided. Seems to work with Eval. Anything wrong with that here?

Comment: This is not what I think about when I think of metadata. What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to make bmi a global variable on purpose?

Also, you are probably missing the underweight category, not that it is relevant to coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `eval` method will evaluate your string as Ruby code. **BUT...**

### eval is fragile

Your string contains the `return` keyword, which *always* returns from a method call. If you `eval` that string inside a method, any code that comes after it will never run because the method will return. If you `eval` that outside of a method, you'll get a `LocalJumpError` exception because `return` is only valid inside a method. I can imagine this causing all sorts of mysterious bugs in your code.

### eval is dangerous

You say the metadata comes from your side, but you're still opening up a huge failure point in your code when you `eval` because it could do *literally anything*. That one call to `eval` could wipe the entire disk, it could download and run an exploit, it could even rewrite your script into a malicious AI with a hatred for humanity. There is really no point in using such a powerful method when you just want to do some numerical comparison.

### eval is confusing

Realistically, you're probably fine using `eval`. Your code will work and the world won't end. But *even then* it's terrible because it creates completely unreadable code. Any programmer reading your script (including yourself, six months later when you come back to fix something) will reach that `eval` and think "Uh... what exactly does this do?" In cases like this, you should always store as little logic in the DB as possible, and do the rest of the calculation in the code. How would you do that in this case? I can think of a few options.

#### Store only the intervals

With a DB schema like

```
table BMIIntervals (
  MinValue    Double,
  Description String
)
```

You could store the rows

```
18.5, 'healthy'
25,   'overweight'
30,   'obese'
```

Then you can easily do the calculation in Ruby:

```
intervals = db.query("SELECT * FROM BMIIntervals ORDER BY MinValue DESC")
intervals.each { |row| return row[1] if $bmi >= row[0] }
return nil
```

#### Store only the calculation name

Or if the BMI intervals are fixed, and the metadata says what kind of calculation to do, you could simply define the calculation in Ruby:

```
module MetadataFuncs
  def self.bmi
    return 'obese' if $bmi > 30
    return 'overweight' if $bmi >= 25
    return 'healthy' if $bmi >= 18.5
  end
end
```

Then your metadata string would be just `"bmi"` and instead of `eval(metadata)` you could do `MetadataFuncs.send(metadata)`. This way you know exactly what code the metadata might call, even without seeing what data are in the database.

Comment: Thank you, great answer.